# Maximum profit that can be obtained - Buying and Selling

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Say we have an accurate prediction  of Messi’s prices for a period of `N` days. The prediction is given as a list in which `p_i` represents the player’s price in day `i`. Bob plans to make multiple, successive transactions during this period, but CAN’T have more than one Messi at a time, and therefore needs to sell him before buying him again.

Bob starts out with a limited budget `B` and can’t buy a Messi which costs more than he can afford. Of course, Bob can add to his budget any profit he gets from buying and selling his Messis. Luckily for him, some of the times he starts with a Messi from opening a random gift pack beforehand.

At the end Bob just wants to have as much profit as possible, and sell hist last Messi.

---

**Input format :**

On the first line of the input file, you will find 3 integers, N, B and M.

N represents the number of days for which Bob has a prediction of Messi’s price.
B represents Bob’s initial budget.
M can be either 0 or 1; 0 if Bob starts without an initial Messi to sell and 1 if he does start with an initial Messi to sell.

On the next line you will find N integers: p1, p2, … , pN, separated by a whitespace, in which pi, represents Messi’s price on day i.

---

**Given testcases**

**Test 1**

7 5 0

20 10 30 5 10 10 20

**Correct answer : 15**

Explanation : Bob starts with an initial budget of 5 and no initial Messi to sell. He cannot buy any Messi until his price drops to 5, so his profit is only (20-5) = 15

---

**Test 2**

7 0 1

20 10 50 80 60 20 10

**Correct answer: 90**

Explanation:
Bob starts with an initial budget of 0 and one Messi to sell. Therefore he sells his initial Messi for 20, buys him back for 10 and sells him for 80, so his profit is 20 + (80-10) = 90

---

This problem was given to me in an interview and I haven't been able to produce a functioning solution. In the meantime I've found a few simpler variations on this problem such as [Maximum profit by buying and selling a share at most twice](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-profit-by-buying-and-selling-a-share-at-most-twice/) , but I've been unsuccessful in understanding how to adapt the thinking to my problem.

So far I've only been able to come up with a brute force solution that goes way beyond the time restrictions I was given (0.1 seconds for C++, where 1 <= N <= 10^5).

I'm looking for a solution and a way of thinking about this kind of problem, I can't seem to find the right way to think about this.

Comment: Please explain how is my question off-topic. After looking at the "Help" section, I've found that appropriate questions may involve: **a specific programming problem** , or
a software algorithm, or
software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Comment: A very broad, general question like this without any code is usually considered off-topic for this site, which is more for solving specific problems with code. It's possible that http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ might be more suited for this quesiton.

Comment: How is this question broad ? This is a very specific problem with very specific requirements. As stated on the 'on-topic' section, the question doesn't need to have any code attached as long as it is based around concepts in the aforementioned list. " We feel **the best** (not strictly necessary) Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…[above list]...**then you’re in the right place to ask your question!**"

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite following. Could you break this down to 1/8 oz, 1/4oz, 1 oz, etc. or maybe even grams. That would be nice.

Comment: The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:

"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." I'm not following either. What does this have to do with my question ? If you can't solve a problem that doesn't make the statement ill-formed, it just means you can't solve the problem.

Comment: @RandomDavis when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use dynamic programming.

1. Let's define `f0(i)` as the maximum budget we can obtain if we don't have Messi at the beginning of the day `i`.
   Let `f1(i)` be the same value in case we've got him.
2. Base values for `i = 0` depend on whether we have him at the very beginning or not.
3. The transitions go as follows:

   - We can go from `i` to `i + 1` and do nothing
   - If we have Messi, we can sell him (setting `f0(i + 1) = max(f0(i + 1), f1(i) + price(i))`)
   - If we don't have him and our budget is big enough, we can buy him 
     (doing `f1(i + 1) = max(f1(i + 1), f0(i) - price(i))`)
4. The answer is `f0(n)` (which mean that all days passed and we don't have him).

This solution clearly requires a linear amount of time and space, so any
reasonable C++ implementation should fit your requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for posting a solution so fast! But I don't fully understand your approach yet. First, how do you actually set the initial values for f0(0) and f1(0) ?  For instance, if we don't have Messi f0(0) = initial_budget because we can't sell so we only have our initial budget, but what about f1(0) ?

Comment: @user43389 If we have him, `f0(0) = -infinity` and `f1(0) = B`. Otherwise, `f0(0) = B` and `f1(0) = -infinity`.

Comment: Another thing that still doesn't make sense to me... Take f0(1) for instance, it hasn't been computed before the loop yet we try to set it to max(f0(1), f1(0) + price(0)), won't the result always be f1(0) + price(0) ?

Comment: Also, while iterating, you gave 3 branches, either we have or don't have Messi, or we skip.. But we're always within any of the first two so when do you actually do nothing?

Comment: @user43389 Yes, we can always skip.

Comment: Yes, but when? Like I said, we're always in one of those states : we either have messi, or we don't; so when do you actually decide to just go to i + 1 without doing anything?

Comment: @user43389 It always goes like `f0(i + 1) = max(f0(i + 1), f0(i))` and `f1(i + 1) = max(f1(i + 1), f1(i))`. There is nothing to decide here. We do it unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

First simplification of the problem is to convert the initial "gift" of Messi to an equal amount of money at the initial price of Messi. The user has a choice to either buy that Messi back or not at the beginning.

Afterwards, you would find the first price that's low enough for the user to buy a Messi, and discard every prediction before that. Then, find all the *local* minimal and *local* maximal of the predicted prices, and buy on all the minimals and sell on all the maximals, but remember not to buy back if the local minimal is the last prediction.

This should solve the problem in O(N).

EDIT: A local minimal or maximal can be found by the 2nd-degree difference of the sequence:

```
d[i] = p[i+1] - p[i]
d2[i] = d[i] - d[i-1]
```

If `d2[i] > 0`, then it's local minimal; if `d2[i] < 0`, then it's local maximal. Obviously there will be some boundary conditions that you need to take care of, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 0):

```
// input
long predictionLength;
long budget;
bool startWithMessi;
long prediction[MAX_PREDICTION_LENGTH];

// output
long profit;

ifstream fin;
fin.open( DATA_FILE_NAME );
fin >> predictionLength >> budget >> startWithMessi;
for( long day = 0; day < predictionLength; day++ )
  fin >> prediction[day];
fin.close();

long money = budget;
bool messi = startWithMessi;
long dayIndex = 0;
while( dayIndex < predictionLength )
{
  if( messi )
  {
    if( dayIndex == predictionLength - 1
      || prediction[dayIndex] > prediction[dayIndex + 1] )
    {
      money += prediction[dayIndex];
      messi = false;
    }
  }
  else
    if( dayIndex < predictionLength - 1
      && prediction[dayIndex] < prediction[dayIndex + 1]
      && money >= prediction[dayIndex] )
    {
      money -= prediction[dayIndex];
      messi = true;
    }
  dayIndex++;
}

profit = money - budget;

cout << profit << endl;
```